# Proof that expression is integer, $\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility, factorial

can you help me with this excercises..

## Proof that expression is integer,

$$\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}$$

I've tried for induction!!

$p(1):\frac{(2)!}{2}=1 $

for $p(k)=\frac{(2k)!}{k!(k+1)!}$

for $p(k+1)=\frac{(2k+2)!}{(k+1)!(k+2)!}$

where,

$$\frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)!}{(k+1)(k!)(k+2)(k+1)!}=\frac{2(k+1)(2k+1)(2k)!}{(k+1)(k+2)(k!)(k+1)!}$$For hypothesis:
$$\frac{2(2k+1)}{(k+2)},$$

how can I follow??

help me??

Comment: Almost surely this question itself or some very similar one has been asked right here...

Comment: Look up Catalan numbers.

Comment: yes,, but i dont know how do it,,,

Comment: you can use second induction principle...

Answer (score 2):

See
$$\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!} = \frac{(2n)!}{n!n!(n+1)} = {2n \choose n}\frac 1{n+1}$$
Then look at Wikipedia [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: but, how proof that expression is integer?? for induction

Comment: @YobaniOrdoñez- Look at the Wikipedia article he linked. It's **right there**.

Comment: Or you could just write : $$\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}= {2n \choose n}\frac 1{n+1} = {2n \choose n} - {2n \choose n+1}$$ and binomial coefficients are integers

Answer (score 1):

From wikipedia, I am picking out the relevant part that lends itself to proof by induction -

$C_n$ is the number of ways to correctly match $n$ pairs of brackets (Dyck Language) in a string word consisting of these $n$ pairs of brackets. This means that the number of opening brackets is never less than the number of closing brackets in any substring derived out of the original string starting from its beginning and that the number of opening brackets is equal to the number of closing brackets. We denote a (possibly empty) correct string with $c$ and its inverse (where "$[$" and "$]$" are exchanged) with $c^+$. Since any c can be uniquely decomposed into $c = [ c_1 ] c_2$, summing over the possible spots to place the closing bracket immediately gives the recursive definition -

[image: Catalan Numbers - Recurrence Relation definition based on Dyck Language interpretation]

This definition can be used to easily prove the hypothesis using strong induction principle